# How do I use 'Masonry' and keep the Bootstrap page content responsive?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I am using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) on a new site for two different pages. This is also a Bootstrap site so I am looking for the content to be responsive. Under the current configuration I can do non-responsive Masonry animated sort or I can have responsive without the animated sort, but I can't bring the two together.

Animated without responsive: http://rouviere.net/our-work/

Responsive without animated: http://rouviere.net/photo/portfolio/

The key in all this is the id="our-work" which ties into this jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#our-work').masonry({
        singleMode: true,
        itemSelector: '.project:not(.hidden)',
        isFitWidth: false,
        isAnimated: true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filters a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filters .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'All-Work') {$('.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');} else {

            $('.project').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {$(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');} else {$(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');}
            });
        }
        $('#our-work').masonry('reload');
        return false;
    });
    $('a:contains("-")').html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/-/g, '<span class="hideme">-</span>');
});

$("a.project_link").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").hide();
    $(this).next(".info_overlay").show();
        });

$(".info_overlay").mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().find("img").show();
  });
});
```

Here is the code from the page that has the animated sort:

```
<div  id="our-work" class="row">   
<div class="container"> 

<div class="project col-xs-12 col-sm-3 Our Work Photography ">
<a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/holi-festival">
<img src="http://www.rouviere.net/resources/photos/Angel_colors.jpg" alt="Holi Festival" >

<div class="info_overlay" style="display:none;">
<h3>Holi Festival</h3>
<p>Holi Festival - A Good time was had by all</p>
<p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/holi-festival">VIEW</a></p>
</div><!-- end info_overlay -->
</a>
</div><!-- end project -->

<div class="project col-xs-12 col-sm-3 Our Work Media-Integration Websites Content-Management Branding-and-Logo Photography Video Print Topics Religion ">
<a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/christmas-nativity">
<img src="http://www.rouviere.net/resources/photos/Apex_Navitity_2010-069.jpg" alt="Christmas Nativity" >

<div class="info_overlay" style="display:none;">
<h3>Christmas Nativity</h3>
<p>Christmas lights at Temple Square in Salt Lake City, Utah.</p>
<p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/christmas-nativity">VIEW</a></p>
</div><!-- end info_overlay -->
</a>
</div><!-- end project -->

<div class="project col-xs-12 col-sm-3 Our Work Media-Integration Websites Mobile-sites Content-Management Branding-and-Logo Photography Video Print Topics Clean Energy Illustration & design ">
<a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/reap-renewable-energy-and-preservation">
<img src="http://www.rouviere.net/resources/photos/reap-home-page-copy.jpg" alt="REAP" >

<div class="info_overlay" style="display:none;">
<h3>REAP</h3>
<p>We built REAP a completely responsive site.</p>
<p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/reap-renewable-energy-and-preservation">VIEW</a></p>
</div><!-- end info_overlay -->
</a>
</div><!-- end project -->

</div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- row -->
```

If you remove the id="our-work" it kills the animation but the content becomes responsive. I am looking for a win-win where the content is responsive and animated as well and could use some insights for a solution.

Comment: Without an isolated fiddle or bin, I'm not going to trouble shoot, but you use the row as the container masonry writes styles to it. Since the id is used for the script, just make it row > div#our-work in your html and see what happens. Why not use something that's easier to deal with: http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

Comment: That is, put a div just inside the row or wrap the row in the our-work div. See if that works. don't apply a style to #our-work